# what is the point of these empty if blocks?

Tags: c, gcc

i'm reading the source code of [http-parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser) and came across some if statements with empty blocks. here's an example ([source](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/blob/master/test.c#L1542))

```
int
dontcall_message_begin_cb (http_parser *p)
{
  if (p) { } // gcc
  fprintf(stderr, "\n\n*** on_message_begin() called on paused parser ***\n\n");
  abort();
}
```

the comment merely mentions 'gcc' which (to me) is not very helpful. what is the point of these?

Comment: Probably to avert the unused parameter warning. In that case, you can just leave it unnamed instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is someone trying to suppress the "unused parameter" warning.

The canonical way to do this is `(void)p;`, but I'm guessing the author of the code didn't know about that.